# How to tweak the following netlogo code so that it actually executes a correlated random walk

Tags: netlogo

Consider the following code for correlated random walk in NetLogo. It takes a random turning angle and random step lengths from a wrapped Cauchy and weibull distributions respectively, and performs a correlated random walk.

```
turtles-own [ orient step ]

  
to-report turning-angle-range [ #min #max ] 
 report #min + random-float ( #max - #min ) 

end 

to-report turning-angles-dist [ #correlation #mean-turning-angle] 

let turning-angle ( ( 1 - #correlation ^ 2) / ( 2 * 180 * ( 1 + (#correlation ^ 2 ) - 2 * #correlation * cos ( ( turning-angle-range 0 180 ) - #mean-turning-angle ) ) ) ) 

 report turning-angle 

end  

to-report weibull-dist [ #shape #scale #mean-step-length ] 

let mean-step-length ( ( #shape / #scale ) * ( ( #mean-step-length / #scale ) ^ ( #shape - 1 ) ) * exp ( ( #mean-step-length / #scale ) ^ ( #shape ) ) ) 

report mean-step-length 

end  

     
to Correlated-Random-Walk 

 ask turtles [

  pen-down

  set orient turning-angles-dist corr-eff mean-turn-angle 

set heading orient 

set step weibull-dist 2 10 mean-move-length 

  fd step 

] 

tick 

end
```

The problem I am having now is that, the correlated randomwalk does not actually occur the way it should. The turtles just move at in 180 degree vertical lines across the world. I am guessing that the random angles and step lengths that should be selected at each tick are not happening or feeding into the walk procedure as they should. Please help.

Comment: what is `corr-eff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you paste in a bunch of code, make sure that it runs if copied and pasted.
2. The problem is quite different than you think.  To see that, replace your `Correlated-Random-Walk` with the following:

.

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    pen-down ;but move this to setup
    Correlated-Random-Walk
  ]
  tick
end

to Correlated-Random-Walk 
  set heading heading + one-of [-1 1] * 10000 * turning-angles-dist corr-eff mean-turn-angle 
  set step weibull-dist 2 10 mean-move-length 
  fd 50 * step 
end
```

The only change is scaling the results of `turning-angles-dist` and `weibull-dist`.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I am new to stack exchange so I am catching up on formalities. The code I posted actually worked for me so I am not sure as to why it did not work for you. I am wondering if it may be more prudent to change scaling of the two distributions within the functions themselves!

Comment: @nigus21 Your model uses interface globals.  When you copy just the code tab, these are not copied.
I agree, you should rewrite those functions.  I was only diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @Allan It seems that changing the scaling coefficients within the angular and step distribution functions will help me rescale the correlated random walk, if you agree, any suggestions would be welcome. Yes, my model uses interface globals, and that is perhaps why it did not work for you at first. Thanks.